# Kubernetes: How to manage multiple separate deployments of the same app

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

We're migrating our app's deployments from using VMs to Kubernetes and as my knowledge of Kubernetes is very limited, I'm lost how I could set up deployment for multiple clients.
Right now we have a separate VM for each client but how to separate the clients in Kubernetes in a way that will be cost and resource efficient and easy to manage?

I managed to create dev and staging environments using namespaces and this is working great.
To update dev and staging deployment I just use `kubectl apply -f <file> --namespace staging`.

Now I need to deploy app to production for several clients (50+). They should be completely separate from each other (using separate environment variables and secrets) while code should be the same. And I don't know what is the best way to achieve that.

Could you please hint me what is the right way for that in Kubernetes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Kustomize](https://kustomize.io). It provides purely declarative approach to configuration customization to manage an arbitrary number of distinctly customized Kubernetes configurations.

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/tree/master/examples

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Kustomize seems very useful and awesome.
I will definitely invest some time into learning it later but can you please tell me if it can allow me to just update all client's deployments without hard-coding all of them somewhere in the code?
Because if it will still require me to hard-code all of them then I'll stick to just hard-coding them in the `kubectl apply -f <file> --namespace <client>` command to save the time.

Answer (score 0):

- one (or a set of namespaces) by customer
- [kustomize](https://kustomize.io/) has a very good patterns system to handle generic configuration and several adaptation by clients
- use `NetworkPolicy` to isolate network between clients